# How do you code an error message for the wrong user input?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to Write a program, that takes input (from STDIN) of a number N, then prints N lines containing "Hello".
0< Max number in Input <=100

I am using Python 3.

User  Input = abc

I've tried using if/elif/else to produce an "Error" message if the user inputs anything other than an integer. However, I think my last elif statement opposes the fact that I'm calling the "line" input an integer.

When I use a string as my test case I get a coding error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/temp/file.py", line 3, in <module>
  line = int(sys.stdin.readline())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc'
```

Code:

```
import sys

line = int(sys.stdin.readline())
if line<1:
  print("Error")
elif line>100:
  print("Error")
elif line != int:
  print("Error")
else:
  print("Hello\n" * line)
```

Comment: You're interested in exception handling: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Haha, it's a good try. But `line != int` isn't how you check for types. :) You'll need to handle input right after the `.readline()`.

Comment: Can you share an example?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `try/except` statement:

```
>>> try:
  l = int(input())
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid Input")


abc
Invalid Input
```

If you want it to keep prompting the user until they enter valid input, use a `while` loop:

```
while True:
    try:
        l = int(input())
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Input")
```